# Desing of form in spring

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, web

I am using spring framework. This question mainly concerns about design and implementation.

1. In my project, I have to use many forms and most of them are different. What is the recommended way of implementing forms in spring. Using Model?
2. I want to use ajax for forms submissions. The forms in the project are really huge having 8-15 fields. Is it a good way to use ajax for such huge forms? If yes, how can I do it? Can I use model attribute?

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to do this is to use form backing objects. For example, with a form like

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

You would create a DTO class

```
public class UserForm {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    public UserForm() {}
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then your `@Controller` handler method can map as

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String handleFormSubmit(@ModelAttribute UserForm userForm /*, more */) {
    /* logic and return */
}
```

And Spring will be able to bind the value from the `name` attribute of `input` elements to the fields of the class.

**AJAX doesn't care about the size of your forms.**